# Dissolved area of polygons using the gArea function of rgeos?

Tags: r, area, dissolve, rgeos

I am taking occurrence point data (in the form of individual Lat/Long points), and adding a 1km buffer around them using `gBuffer()` in R package `rgeos`.

I'm then using the function `gArea()` to calculate the total area of the generated shapefiles. However, the result is the sum of each polygon's area, such that overlapping polygons are counted multiple times.

What I am hoping to get is only the total area of their footprint (essentially equivalent to a dissolved shapefile in ArcGIS).

Because I need to do this process for over 120 species, I'm looking for an automated approach in R rather than manually dissolving the shapefiles in ArcGIS.

```r
# Generate 1km point buffers. Projected CRS for function: USA Contiguous albers equal area 
geodata_Albers <- spTransform(dat_sp, crs.albers)

# Create 1 km buffer and add the total area to the AOOs dataframe.
sp_buffer_1km <- gBuffer(geodata_Albers, width = 1, byid= TRUE) 

AOOs[i,]$buffer_1km <- gArea(sp_buffer_1km, byid = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `byid=TRUE` when buffering. `byid=TRUE` creates a buffer for each row in the data frame. With `byid=FALSE` the function creates a single buffer polygon. Try plotting it to see what happens.